# Why Autocomplete function is not working using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the `id` but `$("#hiddenId").val(ui.item.id);` is showing `undefined`. The strange part is that I am getting the `value` and  `id` here in this part.

```
 value: item.Name,
  id: item.id
```

My complete `JavaScript` code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#txtA").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
           // debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Complete/',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "Post",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                     // debugger;
                        return {
                            value: item.Name,
                            id: item.id
                        };
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
             debugger;
             $("#hiddenId").val(ui.item.value);
             $("#hiddenId").val(ui.item.Id);
        },
        minLength: 1
    });
});
```

My `.cshtml` code:

```
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.txtA)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.hiddenId)
```

Please guide me where I am going wrong. The same code works for another project. I am out of idea. Anyone please guide me.

Comment: `Id` is not equal to `id` (javascript is case sensitive)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I got the solution now. Thank you for guiding me.